# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo & NoClassDefFoundError in Android

Tags: java, android

When I run my Android APP with AndroidStudio,then it happened:

```
 AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shop/com.example.shop.activity.WelcomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.shop.activity.WelcomeActivity" on path: DexPathList[dexElements=[zip file "/data/app/com.example.shop-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.shop-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2272)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2398)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5383)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.shop.activity.WelcomeActivity" on path: DexPathList[dexElements=[zip file "/data/app/com.example.shop-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.shop-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
               at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.newActivity(Unknown Source)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2263)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2398) 
               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5383) 
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853) 
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've googled a lot of answers,and I've tryed:

1. Eclipse BuildPath-->I'm using Android Studio.
2. No complete class name for Activity in Manifest.I've completed...
3. "multiDexEnabled true" in gradle? It didn't work yet.

For multiDexEnabled , actually it worked for a little while.But an Hour later,It happened:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for MainActivity...

I've confused by this for sevral days,please HELP...

Comment: add Your  manifest file

Comment: I think you try delete build folder then rerun it.